# TYPO3 saving Backend content in another database

Tags: database, typo3, typoscript

I want to store content from my Backend in another database.

So let's say i have this in my Backend:

[image: Value in the Backend to be stored in a different DB]

How can i save the value (e.g. the float value in the picture) in another database?

The reason why i need this, is, because i have another database, which is being used for some dynamic content loaded onto my Website with PHP.

Hopefully, someone has an idea and can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve that. I just assume that you want to create relations between the `tt_content` table of TYPO3 and some external table in a different database or even different storage engine (web-service, file-system, ...).

In that case you could extend the `TCA` of the `tt_content` table by an additional property, let's call it `external_reference`. The backend form then should provide an additional selector field that allows to chose entities of the external data-source.

The following example assumes that your extension key is called `my_extension`, this has to be adjusted of course to the actual naming.

You can do so by putting the following configuration to your extension in the folder `typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`:

```
<?php
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content',
    [
        'external_reference' => [
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'External Source',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'items' => [
                    ['-- none --', 0]
                ],
                'itemsProcFunc' => ExternalReferenceSelection::class . '->render',
                'default' => 0,
            ]
        ],
    ]
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'tt_content',
    'external_reference'
);
```

Then you have to implement the selector and the retrieval from the external source, like e.g.

```
<?php
class ExternalReferenceSelection
{
    public function render(array $parameters)
    {
        $references = ExternalReferenceRepository::instance()->findAll();
        foreach ($references as $reference) {
            $parameters['items'][] = [
                $reference->getTitle(),
                $reference->getIdentifier()
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

To be able to persist the selected reference, you have to extend the SQL schema of `tt_content` as well in `typo3conf/ext/my_extension/ext_tables.sql`

```
#
# Table structure for table 'tt_content'
#
CREATE TABLE tt_content (

    external_reference int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL

);
```

The database schema is updated by invoking the database analyzer in the TYPO3 Install Tool, or by (re-)installing the extension in the Extension Manager.

Answer (score 1):

I would use either a hook which updates the foreign database with the value which is triggered if something is changed in the TYPO3 backend or I would use a scheduler task / command controller which is triggered by CLI and runs all x minutes and changes the values in the database.

Comment: It should also be noted, that you can only choose to have full tables in another database, but never just some of the fields.

Comment: Thank you for answering :) Someone got some links to some "tutorials" for that? And is it also possible, to load the value from the db into the TYPO3 Backend? So if the value is changed somewhere else, it is updated in the Backend automatically